# Can't finish massive update with Linq

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, azure

I want to do a massive update with LINQ, something like:

```
foreach (Message message in db.Messages.ToList())
{
     // Some update on the message object (eg. message.Body = message.Body.Replace(....))
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

`db.Messages` are all the messages in the db, mapped with EF, ie: `DbSet<Message>`

There are, say, 500.000 messages in the db, and it seems that the previous code takes too long so I can't execute it. It throws error 502 before it ends executing. No ASP.NET or C# error (running on Azure), just a server error.

[image]

I don't want to do this with pure SQL (connected to the MS SQL Server), though I know that would be a solution.

Comment: If you're using Azure Web Sites, turn on remote debugging and attach Visual Studio to it and see if you can catch the error message. You can also enable detailed errors and then download them as a zip file. 20000 is a lot though, what happens if you just try a smaller number to see if everything's working?

Comment: Yes, with small amounts works fine. Indeed that was another approach I used before. Can't do the 20.000 updates at once?

Comment: Can't you increase `db.Database.CommandTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way: SQL. [Check Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

```
using (var db = new YourContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = db.Database.SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Messages SET Body = REPLACE(Body, 'pattern', 'replacement'");
}
```

If you don't want to do that, you should go with splitting work into chunks, but you probably need different context for each chunk, to prevent context from caching all already updated entities. Use `Skip`/`Take` combination to get proper items from database.

```
var chunkSize = 500;
int updatedItems;
int changes;

do
{
    using(var db = new YourContext())
    {
        foreach (Message message in db.Messages.Skip(updatedItems).Take(chunkSize).ToList())
        {
            // Some update on the message object (eg. message.Body = message.Body.Replace(....))
        }

        changes = db.SaveChanges();
        updatedItems += changes;
    }
} while(changes > 0)
```

Comment: This is exactly why I ended up doing, using Take and Skip. I think it is practically impossible to make all the updates at once in the applicacion level. Of course that at the db level (SQL) it is possible, but the query was not simple at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to break in chunks:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (Message message in db.Messages.ToList())
{
     if((i % 500) == 0)
     {
     // Some update on the message object (eg. message.Body = message.Body.Replace(....))
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
     else
     {
     // Some update on the message object (eg. message.Body = message.Body.Replace(....))
     }
     i++;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: have you done this yourself in similar cases?, also: there should be one db.SaveChanges(), shouldn't it?

Comment: when you call SaveChanges, it will "commit". In this case, every 500 rows, commit, that's why I've called multiple times. I've used in the past with EF 4.x versions.

Comment: So the last db.SaveChanges() in your answer code shouldnt be within the else block?

Comment: no. I'll create groups of 500 statements. The last one (outside the for) is used in case where there are less than 500 items or, the last group will have less than 500 statements.

Comment: and the update statement (message.Body = blah), shouldnt be before the if instead of being in both cases of the if?

Answer (score 0):

For simple batch updates, have a look at [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). Its way faster because it creates one statement for a bunch of entities instead of one statement per entity.
Example:

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks.Update(
    t => t.StatusId == 1, 
    t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the DbContext accumulating an ever increasing collection of Message objects which it tracks for changes.

Try setting db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false before the loop and re-enabling after and then using db.Entry(message).State = EntityState.Modified on those messages that you alter.  If you make changes to related objects you'll need to do the same for those too or changes will get ignored when you call db.SaveChanges();

Switching off AutoDetectChangesEnabled can result in some odd side-effects that are hard to track down so it's best to leave this on most of the time. Just switch off in well understood scenarios where you are adding lots of objects or making isolated changes to lots of existing objects.

**Update**
... and I typically do the db.SaveChanges() inside the loop to spread the load on the db

Comment: If I change a reference in the message (eg. message.Author = message.Author.Children[0]), is it ok to just set the modified state in the message and not in the Author too?

Comment: If you haven't made any changes in the Author object there will be no changes that need saving there. The reference to the Author object is held in the message object so just marking the message as modified will be enough.